# Schematic Critique - USB CDC External Data Processor

Tags: schematic

### [Can Skip] The Context

I was usually working with already-built boards and designing PCBs for simple operations like connecting wires, controlling AC using TRIAC SSR etc. However I've never developed a board with MCU onboard, so I'd like to ask if I'm doing anything wrong (except I think that with my skill everything is wrong)...

### About The Device

The device itself is an PC peripheral. It's principle of operation is to get data from PC using HID/CDC, process the data using STM32 MCU (later MCU) and return data to PC. Sometimes during processing it needs to store some data on external FLASH memory (that data is 258-byte sized structure consisting of 256B array and two one-byte variables).

This revision is an proof of concept and minimum viable product for investment showcase. If it will work as intended, then I will probably switch to USB HS through ULPI.

Power consumption during FLASH write operation never exceeded 20mA on breadboard, however I was using UART to communicate with STM32 G031 (Nucleo32 Board).

### About the Component Picking

For power supply I have choosen 200mA fuse and XC6206P332MR power regulator. Voltage should not exceed 5.5V on the PC USB. As it uses USB port, then reverse voltage protection has been ignored. To meet USB specification I've added USBLC6-2SC6 (recommended by manufacturer) as ESD protection.

Then power goes to MCU - STM32L432KBU6. This one has been choosen, because it does not require external crystal to work with USB, which both decreases price of PCB, space used and EMI compatibility. I will use USB SOF to sync clocks.

For the FLASH I think I should go with my favourite W25QXX or W25NXX from Winbond (often used it with Arduino or Pill Boards and never had a problem with it).
32 Mbit should be enough, but possibly it will require 64Mbit of FLASH. WSON Package has been selected, because both W25QXX and W25NXX have same pinout, so it will require only firmware upgrade to upgrade device from NOR to NAND.

All polarized capacitors are tantalum ones (16V). Non-polarized are ceramic 50V. Tolerance for all capacitors are 10%, for resistors 5%.

I know that I could remove C7 debouncer from NRST, but it's useful to have it to prevent multiple resets.
All passive components are 0603 (except fuse, which is 1206), soldered using paste.

Some PCB design rules are written black by side of schematic section. USB traces length will differ by up to 5mil. SPI trace length will differ by up to 3mil.

### Schematic

[image: Schematic rev.2.]

### Update1

a) Replaced Tantalum Caps with Ceramic (10V+, 10%)
b) Added pull-X resistors for W25XXX SPI FLASH, those are useless (never used ones and never had a single problem with this chip using breakouts)
c) Added decoupler for SPI FLASH 
d) Rotated BOOT0 to make ground point downwards 
e) Added some more "testing" decouplers for MCU 
f) Test points will be added during PCB design (for me it's easier to manage them later)

Comment: Didn't you already have this same question requesting critique? The same errors are still there. You still can't communicate with the flash chip, and the USB input is not compliant with USB specs, and MCU basic connections are not according to manufacturer suggestions.

Comment: Only thing I can see is the ground that's pointing up on your boot pin.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - I don't know why I used tantalum... some sort of "reflex". Replaced them with low-voltage ceramic caps, hope they will do the job...

And you're right, it's related to crypto and don't worry no sensitive data will be stored on FLASH

Comment: H1M4W4R1 - Hi, as @Justme highlighted, you have deleted at least 2 previous questions ([here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/535565) & [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/535370)) asking about the same design. As often happens in design review questions (which are not always allowed here), those questions produced comments but no answers, so the site allowed you to delete them. But in the process, you deleted the work of people whose comments had helped you. Would you like people to delete your work? Please think before doing that again - you could get a reputation. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because deleting and re-asking (in the hope that you get a good answer) is, to my mind wrong for this site. I have asked mods to delete my answer although I've seriously deleted the main informative text..